# Cannot boot from Samsung SSD 950 EVO after Samsung Magician's Data Migration finished

Tags: samsung-ssd, data-migration, samsung-magician

There's this [Samsung Magician](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/magician/) software that Samsung recommends to use with its Samsung SSD 950 EVO drives and they provide this feature - [Data Migration](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/resources/user-manual/Samsung_SSD_Data_Migration_User_Manual_English_US_revision_v6.pdf). Idea is that it can take a system drive with Windows OS on it and clone it to the new drive. I did it and process finished successfully.

[image]

However new drive is not bootable. Even giving it a higher boot priority in BIOS doesn't have any effect. PC still loads Windows from the old drive.

I'm clearly lacking some step here - I thought it would do everything automagically, since it's... well... a Magician?

Comment: First if you have some spare space make a proper backup of your system. Secondly, after you clone your drive, shut down your PC, disconnect the old drive, and then power up with only the SSD and see if that works.

Comment: @jayarjo can you post a screenshot of disk management (`diskmgmt.msc`). I just did the same Data Migration thing between two samsung drives and am finding the cloned drive seemed partially cloned. It's just listed as `Healthy (Primary Partition)` rather than the source drive's full listing of `Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition)`. The source drive for me is a Raid0 SATA SSD going to a target NVME drive on a PCI card adapter.

Comment: I gave up on it. Using new drive as a file storage only.